# Failed to load dartium when running test

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-unittest

I'm running dart test using [test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) library.

```
pub run test -p dartium
```

When this command is executed I'm getting below error, I have dartium and dart sdk downloaded and in system path.

```
Failed to start Dartium: No such file or directory
  Command: dartium --user-data-dir=/tmp/dart_test_cwDGGO
```

Comment: What operating system? Does the folder `/tmp` exist? Do you have permissions to create subfolders in `/tmp`? Have you tried to launch Dartium manually with this command?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and /tmp folder does not exists. I can manually run dartium, I have tried the same thing on windows box with no luck :(

Comment: Where is your `tmp` folder? `/tmp` is usually available on Linux. Can you run manually with `dartium --user-data-dir=/tmp/xxx`?

Comment: Even in temp folder I cannot see/run dartium. Same behavior on my windows machine

Comment: Where is your temp folder? It doesn't matter if you're in the temp folder when launching Dartium when Dartium is looking for it somewhere else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer tmp folder is at the root level. Below is full error message. <br/> <code> Failed to start Dartium: No such file or directory
  Command: dartium --user-data-dir=/tmp/dart_test_Wh4VBK http://localhost:54530/A2wNo7Wt8_73H_-ItA22m5u6B3wMjTnp/packages/test/src/runner/browser/static/index.html?managerUrl=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54530%2FA2wNo7Wt8_73H_-ItA22m5u6B3wMjTnp%2F0 --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-translate.
</code>

Comment: In your 2nd comment you wrote "`/tmp` folder does not exist", does it, or does it not? What error do you get when you run `dartium --user-data-dir=/tmp/xxx` manually?

Comment: It was hidden and now I figured it out. sorry for confusion.

Comment: Have you verified, that you have sufficient permissions to create a sub-folder within `/tmp`?

Comment: Yes, I have sufficient permissions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you!, I figured out the issue, see my answer.

Comment: On windows, as a general rule for developers, best to create a temp folder outside of your user directory. e.g. md c:\temp, set TEMP=c:\temp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was missing symlink. After adding symlink tests are working.

```
ln -s /path/to/chrome /path/to/dartium
```

where **/path/to/chrome** is your chrome executable from dartium directory